# Set up default app to handle google doc file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps

I'm developing an App for Google Docs. I have 2 users. User A shares a file *.customFileType with user B. I want to know how to setup a default application (customFileType App) to be used/suggested when I try to open the file type *.customFileType

User B opens an email with a link to fizz.customFileType.

[image]

I want to know how to setup a default application (customFileType App) to be used/suggested when I try to open the file type fizz.customFileType

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your application should indicate in the developer console that it supports the specific file extension and MIME type.  This page talks about the steps to go through to [configure your app](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/enable-sdk).

See also this page specifically about [integrating with open](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open) capability.